# Триггер для TreeView HasItem

Tags: wpf, .net

Допустим у меня есть такое представление:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source1}"/>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source2}"/>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source3}"/>
<TreeView/>
```

Как мне лучше сделать триггер, который бы срабатывал на установку HasItem = false в каждом узле? В голову приходит только идея задавать имена узлов и через MultiDataTrigger их отслеживать. Но может быть есть еще варианты?
Спасибо.